# Linking a dynamic lib using Bazel on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, dylib, bazel

I'm compiling my program using Bazel, and I have a dependency on Intel TBB.
Intel TBB only provide dynamic libraries (no static) for good reasons (if you are curious: [ctrl+f static here](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/faq/11?page=1)).

In my bazel WORKSPACE I defined that rule :

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "inteltbb",
    path = "./third_party/intel_tbb",
    build_file = "./third_party/inteltbb.BUILD",
)
```

and in my "inteltbb.BUILD" I have:

```
cc_library(
  name = "dynamic_lib",
  srcs = ["build/macos_intel64_clang_cc8.1.0_os10.12.5_debug/libtbb_debug.dylib"],
  hdrs = glob(["include/**/*.h"]),
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
  strip_include_prefix = "include/"
)
```

Then in my final program (under the cc_binary rule) I have:

```
deps = [
    "@inteltbb//:dynamic_lib", [...]
```

It compile properly, find the headers successfully but at runtime it crashes saying:

```
____Running command line: bazel-bin/build-game
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtbb_debug.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_dmabin/526b91f44cfc47d856222c6b20765cc8/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin_x86_64-fastbuild/bin/build-game
  Reason: image not found
```

I check under the "bazel-bin" folder (where the executable is symlink for runtime execution: bazel-bin/build-game.runfiles/**main**/) and I do have:

- the symlink for the executable (build-game)
- a folder called (brace yourself): `_solib_darwin_x86_64/_U@inteltbb_S_S_Cdynamic_Ulib___Uexternal_Sinteltbb_Sbuild_Smacos_Uintel64_U
  clang_Ucc8.1.0_Uos10.12.5_Udebug` that contain my `libtbb_debug.dylib` for intel tbb.

Also when I run: `otool -l build-game | grep LC_RPATH -A2` the result is:

```
      cmd LC_RPATH
  cmdsize 152
     path $ORIGIN/_solib_darwin_x86_64/_U@inteltbb_S_S_Cdynamic_Ulib___Uexternal_Sinteltbb_Sbuild_Smacos_Uintel64_Uclang_Ucc8.1.0_Uos10.12.5_Udebug (offset 12)
```

I don't understand why my executable doesn't find my dylib. I can't find anything wrong about the otool output but I'm not a mac expert (at all).
Any idea is welcome.

[edit]
If I edit the executable using otool to replace the path to the dylib like that:

```
@executable_path/_solib_darwin_x86_64/_U@inteltbb_S_S_Cdynamic_Ulib___Uexternal_Sinteltbb_Slib/libtbb_debug.dylib
```

Then it works fine. I doesn't feel right that bazel force me to do that at every compilation :/

[edit 2]
A few people asked me the line I used to modify the path of the lib in the executable.
First run:

```
otool -L build-game
```

To spot the path of the lib you want to change. In my case it was: @rpath/libtbb_debug.dylib.
After that run:

```
install_name_tool -change @rpath/libtbb_debug.dylib @executable_path/_solib_darwin_x86_64/_U@inteltbb_S_S_Cdynamic_Ulib___Uexternal_Sinteltbb_Slib/libtbb_debug.dylib build-game
```

to change the path. Note that you can use @executable_path to make it relative to the binary path or you can put an absolute path, up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is already a [known issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3450), and it was just fixed. Sorry for the trouble.

[edit: updated after submitting the fix]

Comment: Thx for the info. In the meantime, on mac, I've an ugly make that will do the trick until the issue is solved in Bazel ...

Comment: Will try it out now, and mark your answer right after :)

Comment: I haven't update the comment because I'm waiting for 0.5.5 to checkout the fix :)

Comment: 0.6.0 coming soon :) https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/release-0.6.0

Comment: I was super excited by the release of 0.6.0 but it didn't fix my issue :/ The Rpath is still the same:
otool -l build-game | grep LC_RPATH -A2
    cmd LC_RPATH
  cmdsize 104
    path $ORIGIN/_solib_darwin_x86_64/_U@inteltbb_S_S_Cdynamic_Ulib___Uexternal_Sinteltbb_Slib (offset 12)

Comment: Even after you run `bazel clean --expunge`?

Comment: If yes, can you pls comment on the issue?

Comment: Yes, even after `bazel clean --expunge` the issue stays exactely the same for me. and the "pretty bad" workaround stay the same. I still have to manually replace the path to the dylib with:
`@executable_path/_solib_darwin_x86_64/_U@inteltbb_S_S_Cdynamic_Ulib___Uexternal_Sinteltbb_Slib/libtbb_debug.dylib`

Comment: I see where's the problem now, osx_cc_wrapper only fixes .so libraries, not .dylibs. If you rename the extension of libtbb_debug.dylib to libtbb_debug.so it should work. I already uploaded a fix for dylib to the pipeline.

Comment: Let me give it a try tonight :) Thx for your help and patience :)

Comment: I guess it's you who is patient :)

Comment: Well I tried more or less everything I could and bazel keep looking for a .dylib even when I have only mention of .so file everywhere in my build script. I also update the question with what I do to update the path the library is looked for in the executable. For now I'm running that after each compilation and well ... It "does the trick".

Comment: Then can you file an issue on our github? Ideally with a repo that I can clone and test?